# What is the correct CronJob annotations format?

Tags: yaml, azure-aks

I am using the following yaml to try and deploy a CronJob into an Azure Kubernetes Service. For some reason it doesnt like the annotations line and throws the error - 'bad indentation of a mapping entry at line 16, column 9:annotations: '.

How should I be formatting this to work correctly?

```
'# $(appName)/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v2alpha1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
    name: $(appName)-electionsdev
    labels:
        app: $(appName)-electionsdev
spec:
    startingDeadlineSeconds: 180
    schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
    concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
    jobTemplate:
        spec:
            template:
                metadata:
                    name: test
                    annotations: 
                        container.apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/$(appName)-electionsdev: localhost/docker-default
                spec:
                    restartPolicy: Never
                    imagePullSecrets:
                        - name: $(dockerAuthSecretName)
                    automountServiceAccountToken: false
                    volumes:
                        - emptyDir: {}
                          name: tmp
                    containers:
                        - name: $(appName)-electionsdev
                          image: frameworkregistry.azurecr.io/correspondenceserver-release
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it without the "name: test":

```
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            container.apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/$(appName)-electionsdev: localhost/docker-default
```